# Custom UITableViewCell reappearing

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am having a problem with custom cell reappearing. I tried to emulate the problem with this example. I have a simple uitableview with 20 rows, my custom cell has a label and UITextfield, the custom cell design with IBOutlets from storyboard. If I type something in textfield at row0, When I scroll, I see same text in textfield at row 14 which is the first row that appears when I scroll. The problem I am trying to solve is more dynamic and I need to load different UIControls dynamically, but I would like to start with this simple example.
here is the code.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 static NSString *CellIdentifier1 = @"TextFieldCellIdentifier";

TextFieldCell *cell = (TextFieldCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier1 forIndexPath:indexPath];


if(!cell)
   cell = [[TextFieldCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier1];
else {
    for (UIView* tempView in cell.contentView.subviews) {
        if(tempView.tag == 1)
          [tempView removeFromSuperview];
    }
}

cell.qTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row];

return cell;
}
```

My custom Cell:

```
@interface TextFieldCell : UITableViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *qTextLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;

@end
```

Comment: This is because the cells are reused. You should read Apple's "Table View Programming Guide for iOS" to familiarize yourself with how table views work.

Answer (score 0):

You don't set the value of textfield text at reused/created cell, obviously the initial value is going to be used which is the text you entered before in case of reused cell or empty text in case of created cell.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow, can you elaborate?

Comment: When the view is reused, only its position is changed, you need to setup all the subviews state: `self.textField.text = savedTextForIndexPath`.

Comment: if I understood correctly, I need to save the values of the textfields somewhere, like NSDictionary or so, so I can lookup the correct value when I need it? If that's the case, I may need to store the data in database because I can have different controls like checkbox, radio buttons, textfields depending on the row type.

Comment: Exactly, and any kind of storage is better than reading data from views. If you go with core data, it will also give you a lot of very convenient features with fetched results controller.